# Is this the most efficient way to parse the string?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of the form `AU 12345T` or `AU 12345T1`; basically it is of the form alphabet characters(s) followed by a number then ending in a one or two character alpha-numeric string.

I am using the following regular expression to get me the result:

```
^[a-z|A-Z]+|[0-9]+|[a-z|A-Z][0-9]?
```

Would this be the most efficient way to parse such a string?

So for the example `AU 12345T`, I want the result to be separated into three tokens: `AU`, `12345`, `T`; for `AU 12345T1` it should be `AU`, `12345`, `T1` (since the ending characters can be alpha-numeric and max length is 2)

Comment: Smells strongly of premature optimization to me.

Comment: For me this look like Regex for license plate.

Comment: Why are you looking for pipes?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

`[A-Za-z]+\s?[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}?`

If you want to separate the strings as you said, put parenthesis around the blocks, like so:

`([A-Za-z]+)\s?([0-9]+)([A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}?)`

This will have the regex return each group individually.

All this being said, you'll probably want to ensure that the final one/two character alphanumeric string always begins with a letter, or else you'll have no way of separating the second token from the third token.